# Can't pip install tensorflow with python 3.8 64bit

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda

I have a conda config file and I can't seem to create an environment with tensorflow and python=3.8

Here is my config file

```
name: proj1
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip
  - pip:
    - matplotlib
    - tensorflow
    - tensorflow-probability
```

Here is the error message :

```
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

I am on Macos 12.6 with M2 chip and my python is 64 bits
`pip --version` gives pip 23.0.1 and `pip3 --version` gives pip 22.2.2
`python --version` gives Python 3.8.16 and `python3 --version` gives Python 3.10.6

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: If upgrading to Python 3.8, then why not install `tensorflow`, etc. from Conda? It provides native **osx-arm64** builds.

Comment: I managed to do it by replacing - tensorflow with - tensorflow-macos and then running conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps in the environment. Then I had to update numpy with pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed